# Can I have a LINQ query that counts total of rows filtered with a where on a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an array that contains data like this:

```
var arr = 
[{count=0, instances=1},
 {count=1, instances=2},
 {count=3, instances=1},
 {count=4, instances=5},
 {count=5, instances=2}]
```

Is it possible using LINQ for me create a query that would show a total of the instances if I was to specify the count?

```
So for example if I did a query with 1 it would give me 3 (from 1+2)
So for example if I did a query with 4 it would give me 9 (from
1+2+1+5)
```

Comment: Can the count column have repetitive value? ex. {count=1, instance=2},{count=1, instance=5}

Comment: No that's not possible

Comment: Check my answer below, perhaps that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var countToTake; // 0 < countToTake <= arr.Length
var instanceCount = arr.Take(countToTake).Sum(item => item.instances)
```

EDIT: See comments

```
var instanceCount = arr.Take(arr.IndexOf(item => item.count == countToTake)).Sum(item => item.instances)
```

Comment: This code wont work. If `countTOTake = 1`, in you case code will take only the first value and sum it up and the result will be 1 whereby expected result was 3

Comment: You did not specify if the code should evaluate the count of items in the collection or the count property. Thus the code Amney Kamat provided is more suitable for your needs.
Also I've updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = arr.Where(x => x.count <= maxCount).Select(x => x.instances).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do you work.

```
int selectedCount = 4 //hardcoded for illustration purpose, you will set this programatically
int sum = arr.Where(x => arr.IndexOf(x) <= (arr.FindIndex(i => i.count.Equals(selectedCount))))
             .Select(x => x.instances).Sum();
```